# How to ensure objects touch in render with material displacement?

Tags: modeling, constraints, displacement

I have created a bunch of connected surfaces:

[image: example].

However, since I am using different displacement materials, in render they no longer touch:

[image: example].

How do I ensure they always remain together even after the material displacement?
Help with coding this or just how to do it in Blender would be amazing!

---

Update after merging surfaces:

[image: merged surfaces]

Comment: Hello, what does it give if you merge the vertices in Edit mode?

Comment: Even though the vertices are the same between the meshes it says that there are no vertices to merge within 0.0001 m.

Comment: If they are separate objects in the outliner you can't merge, you would have to ctrl + j to join objects first

Comment: Ah yes thank you. That is definitely improved. Not sure if there is a way to make it look a bit more realistic. (Updated post and added picture!)